# Spring-Kafka consumer doesn't receive messages automatically

Tags: java, windows, cmd, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot kafka consumer and a spring boot kafka producer,
when I launch the consumer in the terminal and after I launch the producer, the consumer receives the data if and only if I press any keyboard key and I don't know why?
Here is my configuration.

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, DataSet> dataSetConsumerFactory() { /* string group id */
        /* set up le consumer factory */
        String clientId = "pattern-" + groupid;
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress); /* kafka server */
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupid);/* group id */
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId); /* client id */
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest"); /* reset offset */
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(DataSet.class));
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your code and configuration; you are probably missing `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG=earliest`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in windows when you select something in the terminal the running process stops so you have to press any keyboard key to start it again.